# Does using sessions too much slow down performance in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, session

Bit of an odd question, but I'm using sessions a lot in a project.

If I'm using them repeatedly in one page is it better to read them in to a variable once and then use the variable or does it make no difference to be constantly referencing `$_SESSION['name']` in the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does using sessions too much slow down performance in PHP?

Nope.

> does it make no difference to be constantly referencing $_SESSION['name'] in the same page?

it does make no difference.

> is it better to read them in to a variable

$_SESSION['name'] is already a variable, you know.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not mater as $_SESSION['name']  is the same variable as others, just defined in global space as $_SERVER, $_COOKIE